# StateError (Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform). How can I get a doc from firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to flutter. I want to get a specific doc from firestore using its uid and then transfer this doc in a value type that I can handle. BUT i get a breakpoint when I run my application : **StateError (Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)**.
This the code:

```
final cloth = await DatabaseService(uid: uid)
          .clothCollection
          .doc(uid)
          .get()
          .then((doc) => {
                            Cloth(
                    brand: doc.get('brand'),
                    name: doc.get('name'),
                    color: doc.get('color'),
                    url: doc.get('url'))
              });
```

and Cloth :

```
class Cloth {
  final String? name;
  final String? url;
  final String? brand;
  final String? color;

  Cloth({this.name, this.brand, this.color, this.url});
}
```

If there is an easier way to get this doc let me know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's probably doc has no .get() functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get` attribute does not exist on the `DocumentSnapshot`(doc). Instead, you have to use the `data()` method which returns a `Map<String, dynamic>`, or null if the doc does not exist. It's good practice to always check to see if the document exists first before executing further.

```
final cloth = await DatabaseService(uid: uid)
          .clothCollection
          .doc(uid)
          .get()
          .then((doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
            Map<String, dynamic>? data = doc.data();

              return Cloth(
                    brand: data?['brand'],
                    name: data?['name'],
                    color: data?['color'],
                    url: data?['url']);
           } else {
              print('Document does not exist.');
            }
              });
```